# How to sort alphanumeric strings Lexicographically in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sorting, alphanumeric

We have a column in a PostgreSQL table with the following data:

```
1A
1ABCD
1B
ABCD1
2
ABCD2
3
ABCD3
ABCD4
ABCD5
ABCD10
ABCD11
ABCD1111
A
B
```

Expected result after sorting:

```
1
2
3
1A
1ABCD
1B
A
B
ABCD1
ABCD2
ABCD3
ABCD4
ABCD5
ABCD10
ABCD11
ABCD1111
```

We tried doing normal DESC and '([0-9]+)')::BIGINT ASC. But not getting expected sorted results.

Comment: I don't understand your desired sort order. How is `1A` after `2`? That is not lexicographical. It feels more like "If the value is fully numeric than sort it first numerically, for every thing else sort it lexicographically". Does that capture your requirements?

Comment: Yes. If the value is fully numeric than sort it first numerically, for every thing else sort it lexicographically

Comment: Why is B sorted before ABCD1?

Comment: I missed that @Isolated. OP, Lexicographical sort is what is used in a dictionary so having `B` before `ABCD1` doesn't fit either. Is that a typo or legit how it should be sorted, and if it's legit, can you explain what the logic is for putting `B` before `ABCD1`?

Comment: try `order by value !~* '^\d+$', value`

Answer (score 1):

So you can try this just put column name instead of asterisk and column.

> `SELECT * FROM PostgreSQL ORDER BY column ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

Mike O's comment is correct if you have a typo in where you would like B sorted in the mix. However, if you have some complex logic (ie, not truly lexicographical order) and you really want B sorted before ABCD1, then you could use a case statement to help your sorts:

```
select col1, 
case 
  when col1 ~* '[a-z]' is false then 1 --numeric only
  when substring(col1, 1, 1) ~* '[0-9]' is true then 2 --starts with number
  when col1 ~* '[0-9]' is false then 3 --letters only
  else 4 --alphanumeric mixed
end sort1
from my_table
order by 2,1
```

Output:

| col1 | sort1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1A | 2 |
| 1ABCD | 2 |
| 1B | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| ABCD1 | 4 |
| ABCD10 | 4 |
| ABCD11 | 4 |
| ABCD1111 | 4 |
| ABCD2 | 4 |
| ABCD3 | 4 |
| ABCD4 | 4 |
| ABCD5 | 4 |

DB-fiddle found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8WMKLAaWiRf8tEW9RGu8EZ/0).